# How do I capture this struct vector? c++

Tags: c++, class, vector, struct

So I've made a class, one of it's function returns a struct vector, like so:

```
vector<highscore::players> highscore::returnL(){
    load();
    return list;
}
```

So list is basically,

```
struct players {
            string name;
            int score;
    };
    vectors<players> list;
```

In my source cpp, I tried to capture this vector, so I made another struct and struct vector.
Source.cpp:

```
struct players1 {
        string name;
        int score;
};
vector<players1> highscorelist;
```

Then I tried to

```
highscore high; //class' name is highscore
highscorelist = high.returnL();
```

But I get the error message:

```
No operator "=" matches these operands
" operand types are std::vector<players1, std::allocator<players1>> = std::vector<highscore::players, std::allocator<highscore::players>> "
```

Is it not possible to do it this way?
I honestly don't know what to search for so this might have been answered before, apologize if that's the case.

Comment: The vector types aren't the same as the error message says, so you can't.

Comment: But, how are they not the same, what's the difference? edit: oh do they need to be from the exact same struct?

Comment: _"oh do they need to be from the exact same struct?"_ Yes. Why do you need to declare the struct multiple times?

Comment: type differs. Do you really want to have both type `players` and `players1` ? or do you want different instances of of `players`

Comment: Im stupid, I solved it like this

       vector<highscore::players> highscorelist;

Comment: To avoid very cryptic hard to find errors, instead of declaring struct in every module, move it into a header file and include this header file into all the modules that require this struct. Sharing the same definition of a struct will ensure that it is the same in every module. See also: [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reinterpret_cast`, but that's not a good solution. Why don't you use `highscore::player`?

```
std::vector<highscore::player> highscoreList;
highscoreList = high.returnL(); // ok
```

`highscore::player` and `player1` are different types, even though they have the same variables and probably even the same memory layout. You cannot just interchange types like that. Also, if you change one of those types, you have to change the other, which is just a maintenance nightmare if it were possible.

If you can, you could also use `auto`:

```
auto highscoreList = high.returnL();
```